# Python : Is there any way that for loop runs once even if it returns false

Tags: python, loops

I have the loop like this

```
for a in list1:
     for b in list2:
         for c in list3:
             print "Hello"
```

Without using any if else statement. i want that if there are elements in all list then it should repeat as normal but if the list is empty then for loop should behave like its don't exist and runs the code below it once

like if `list3` is empty and `list2` contains `2` elements and `list1` has one element then i should see `hello` 2 times

Comment: Didn't you aks the same question like 45 minutes ago?

Comment: well no one answerd it as i wanted. i even asked in the comments as well but they didn't answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for a in list1 or [None]:
     for b in list2 or [None]:
         for c in list3 or [None]:
             print "Hello"
```

The `None` in `[None]` can be replaced by any other single object.

This way the empty list will be replaced by a list with one element and the loop will proceed once.

Other way (if the variables `a`, `b` and `c` are not important) would be:

```
for i in xrange(max(len(list1), 1) * max(len(list2), 1) * max(len(list2), 1))):
    print 'Hello'
```

**UPDATE**

Your idea of using my code without adapting it correctly:

```
for m,n in zip(l1,l2) or [None]:
```

can be corrected using:

```
for m,n in zip(l1 or [None], l2 or [None]):
```

or

```
for m,n in zip(l1, l2) or [[None, None]]:
```

Comment: +1 sweet and beautiful. I love python

Comment: really that was very good and clean.

Comment: It says None Type object is not iterable

Comment: @user2294401 - you've changed my code, didn't you?

Comment: Although I like your last code snippet I would have written it as `print('Hello\n' * max(len(list1), 1) * max(len(list2), 1) * max(len(list2), 1)))`

Comment: i am using this `for m,n in zip(l1,l2) or [None]:`

Comment: @pwagner - hopefully the OP doesn't want to print Hellos only…